# how to add a home button from css in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile site. Its around 50 html pages , and i need to add in my header a simple home button. Is it possible to add this button from the CSS , or i need to open one by one all the html files and add it?

The button is simple as that :

```
<a href="http://myHomepage.com" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a>
```

Also how can i make this button appear on the left side? For some reason it appears on the right.

Also how can i change the theme color of my header from the CSS instead of changing it on every file?

Thank you very much

Comment: you have too many questions in one. It's better to separate your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ZUYmt/

```
$(document).on('pageinit',  function(){       
    $('<a href="#index" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left" data-theme="a">Home</a>').button().appendTo('[data-role="header"]');
});
```

1. No you cant add a button using only CSS but you can do it with jQuery, example can be found in a working example on top.
2. For button ti be displayed on a left side change button attribute **`class="ui-btn-right"`** to **`class="ui-btn-left"`**
3. It can be done like this:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforecreate',  function(){  
       $('[data-role="header"]').attr('data-theme','a');        
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your website does not use template files to create the layout and is built page-by-page then your best option is to use jQuery to add a home button to every page. If it does use template files then use these because this would avoid the problem of the buttons not being rendered in javascript-free environments.

With regards to your other questions you will need to show us a little more code and perhaps set up a fiddle.